# Moving tables to file-groups that does not contain any index

Tags: sql-server

I have create 5 staging tables and also 5 filegroups in the sql server database. How do I move 5 staging tables to the 5 filegroups created. Please note that the tables does not have any clustered indexes or anything. It just has data. Currently all the 5 staging tables are in the PRIMARY filegroup. I need to

```
Staging1  to filegroup1
Staging2  to filegroup2
Staging3  to filegroup3
Staging4  to filegroup4
Staging5  to filegroup5
```

I tried the following but is giving me a compile error

```
USE XYZ
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[staging1 ]  WITH MOVE TO filegroup1 ;
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

There are only two ways to do this:

Create a clustered index on the table and put the clustered index on the new filegroup with something like:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CIX_staging1 ON staging1 (column1, column2, column3)
```

Drop and re-create the table on the new filegroup

I recommend creating the clustered index, every table should have one.